# Change logon account of a service using powershell when password has special symbols

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

I'm running following powershell script to change logon user account of a remote service and then start it.

```
$result = $remoteService.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$logonAccount, $logonPassword,$null,$null,$null)

    if ($result.ReturnValue -eq '0') 
    {
        write-host "logon account changed"
        $remoteService.StartService();
    } 
    else 
    {
        write-host "Error: $result.ReturnValue"
    };
```

If my password contains only alphanumeric chars, I can see that service starts as shown in result below

```
logon account changed
ReturnValue      : 0
```

However another account includes password with special characters like @, # and - , if I use this account my service start fails with error code 15.

```
logon account changed
ReturnValue      : 15
```

Same is the result of I use sc command (example)

```
sc \\servername config servicename obj= domain\accountname password= w@e#dF-sxs32
sc \\servername  start servicename

[SC] StartService FAILED 1069:
The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

I can manually change the logon user of service and start it successfully from the Windows services.msc UI using the same account as mentioned above. So I thought issue could be with the password.

I have struggled a lot with this. can anyone please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Enclose the password in double quotes: `password= "w@e#dF-sxs32"`

Answer (score 1):

I checked, your sc command works very well.

```
sc \\mycomp config myservice obj= mycomp\User1 password= w@e#dF-sxs32
```

So, the issue is not in password with @#-_

It seems your domain\accountname user does not have rights or privileges to run any service on the servername server.

See MSDN about Add the Log on as a service Right to an Account
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794944(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hi Sergei, I can manually change the logon user of service from the Windows services.msc UI using the same account as mentioned above. So I thought issue can be with the password.

Comment: Great. The services.msc UI adds the Log on as a service Right to an Account. Now do it for 2nd user in UI, then run 
`sc \\servername config servicename obj= domain\accountname password= w@e#dF-sxs32`
for user1.